# A generalisation of the Artin-Tate Lemma

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, reference-request, galois-theory, group-actions

Does the following (standard ?) generalisation of the Artin-Tate Lemma have a name ?

> If $k$ is a field and $R$ is a finitely type commutative $k$-algebra and $G$ is a *finite* group acting on $R$, then the subring of $G$-fixed points $R^G$ is also of finite type over $k$.

Comment: I'm not sure if it has a name, but I would be hesitant to call it a generalization. It's rather a specific case of the lemma.